# How to check where Apache is running or listening on Localhost

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, php, nginx

I just installed Apache on my Ubuntu , But when I write `localhost:` it redirect me to a page.

> Welcome to nginx!
>
> If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed.
>   and working. Further configuration is required.

So, I think on default nginx is installed. So where I can find my Apache ? And I tried `localhost:8080` which redirect me to

> > It works !
>
> If you're seeing this page via a web browser, it means you've setup
>   Tomcat successfully. Congratulations!

Thanks!

Comment: check this out https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: and please confirm: nginx  and apache are 2 different webservers. Tomcat is NOT installed through apache or our lamp installation. What did you install?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"It works !" is the default page you see when Apache is installed. Not sure if other webservers use the same method though(?)

> So where I can find my apache ? And I tried localhost:8080

That would be `localhost:8080`.

In case you want to be perfectly sure...

- `lsof -i` will list open ports and the corresponding applications. `lsof  | grep apache` for apache. Similar: `sudo netstat -anp | grep apache`.
- See `/etc/hosts` for IP addresses connected to names.
- See `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` for settings about the sites that are active for Apache.
- See `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` for the `Listen`. It will have a port-number behind it. That parameter can also be in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`

If `/etc/apache2/` does not exist you did not install Apache. Nginx uses `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and the same style paramaters.

Comment: Actually It was running on 80. I saw on GUI of xamp